# Thymeleaf: Detect hardcoded text

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Is there a chance to automate the search for non-localized text on startup in Thymeleaf Templates and log occurrences?

My Infrastructure: Ant, Spring, Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no clean documented way in which to do it (that I know of).

Having said that, I have done something similar where I wanted to check the template for something and log an occurrence, however the implementation is ugly.

**I have to warn you that this is beyond horrible and because it is not standard is likely to break in future releases so I would use sparingly, and definitely not use in any production code.**

This requires for you template resolver to be cacheble to be `true` - `org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver#setCacheable(true)` the default is `true`.

I was able to do it by extending `org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCacheManager` (you need to set the cache manager on the `org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine`) and overriding `initializeTemplateCache()` that returned a custom version of `org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCache`. My implementation of the cache override the `put(..)` method which passed in a `org.thymeleaf.Template` as the value.

That then has `org.thymeleaf.dom.Document` accessible via `getDocument()` and from there you can recursivly iterate through the children (some of which will be `org.thymeleaf.dom.AbstractTextNode`). In your case you may also want to iterate through all the attributes on element nodes as well.

For you, you will then have to write some logic to determine if the text is not going to be localised, working out whether the `#{}` expression is not being used or if that expression in not in a `th:...="#{}"` tag or being inline `[[#{}]]`

Ugly I know but it works for me. If anyone has a cleaner solution I'm all ears.

Comment: The only thing which is ugly is that you used the CacheManager which depends on cacheable to be true. In our dev environments we all set it to false. So, your answer is really helpful but not applicable to me.